# How to save a ShuffleDataset object?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

I created a dataset by using **from_generator** function from tf.data.dataset API. Then I shuffle my dataset and divide it into batches of size 10. So the pipeline looks like

> dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(batch_size=10)

(For illustration) when I print the first batch, it looks like:

[image]

I want to save the whole dataset. I tried to use the command `dataset.save(path)` but I received an `AttributeError` saying `'ShuffleDataset' object has no attribute 'save'`.

Is there any way to save this dataset?

Thanks

Comment: What is your TF version? I guess ds.save() was introduced in TF 2.11

Comment: yes it works with tf 2.11, thanks!